# Calling an RPC server over WebSocket multiple times from a WebSocket client

Tags: reactjs, websocket, rxjs, event-handling, rpc

I am setting up a **WebSocket** client from a React app to [**aria2's json-rpc**](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html?highlight=dir#rpc-interface) server over WebSockets.

I wish to update a file's download percentage on the app but unfortunately the server doesn't emit any timely event for this. However, it does expose a [`tellStatus`](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html?highlight=dir#aria2.tellStatus) method which I can use to get the details of the file.

The issue is I can only think of calling this endpoint in an interval and then use the response data to build the percentage overtime. Since, I might end up with hundreds of files, this doesn't seem viable.

What would be the best way to get the status for these files and keep it updated timely?

Sample request for one file:

```
const data = {
  jsonrpc: 2.0,
  id: 'qwer',
  method: 'aria2.tellStatus',
  params: ['2089b05ecca3d829'], // gid of the file
};
socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: You should definitely consider using event emitters on you server code which will broadcast message on your client the file download progress.

Comment: that is the issue, aria2c is a library written in C whose methods are exposed through this RPC-Server and the websocket server doesn't expose any event emitters. 
I cannot change the sever code. It has to be on the client